# How to disambiguate selector function?

Tags: haskell, ghc

In GHC 8:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}

data Dog = Dog { name::String }
data Human = Human { name::String }

dog = Dog "Spike"


main = putStrLn $ name dog
```

This code does not compile:

```
Ambiguous occurrence `name'
It could refer to either the field `name', defined at A.hs:4:22
                      or the field `name', defined at A.hs:3:18
```

How to correctly retrieve the name of my dog?

Comment: Ah, ambiguous record fields... wonder if the chain of kludgy fix extensions is infinite? If yes, will we need a `DisambiguateRecordFieldsDisambiguationExtension` extension? — ...Be sure to check out [Nikita Volkov's `records` library](https://nikita-volkov.github.io/record/), which should make these extensions completely unnecessary. — (FTR: I don't think the writers of these extensions are doing a bad job, in fact I've used `RecordWildCards` in the past and found it to work reasonably well. Nevertheless, I daresay it's overall not the right approach.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this should work:

```
main = putStrLn $ name (dog :: Dog)
```

see [DuplicateRecordFields](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Records/OverloadedRecordFields/DuplicateRecordFields) for details:

> Bare uses of the field refer only to the selector function, and work only if this is unambiguous.

and

> However, we do not infer the type of the argument to determine the datatype, or have any way of deferring the choice to the constraint solver.

The example there is very much like yours:

> `bad (p :: Person) = personId p`

this will not work when there is another record with a `personId` field in scope - even if it seems to be obvious :(

Comment: see the citation ... you are right but this is not how it works / is inferred - if you use signatures that is usually no problem

Comment: oh i believe this LANGUAGE extension is going to be one of my favourite!

Comment: yes it's extremely confusing ... I think I'm not gonna use it (in the same module)

Comment: Is this GHC 8.0 only?

Comment: @chi well obviously I am not competent to answer this but the page I linked says "This was implemented as ​Phab:D761 and ​Phab:D1391 and will be in GHC 8.0." so I would interpret that as yes - at the moment it's probably 8.x only

Comment: @Carsten how to see (:t name) in GHCI?

Comment: @IvanKleshnin I don't understand your question - is `:t name` not working in GHCi ?

Comment: Not with double `name` declaration. """ Ambiguous occurrence ‘name’
    It could refer to either the field ‘name’, defined at cc.hs:7:36
                          or the field ‘name’, defined at cc.hs:5:34
"""

Comment: ah sorry I see your problem - you can use `:i name` in this case (it will find you both occurences)

Comment: also this should probably be an GHC issue