# Why is the type not inferred?

Tags: haskell, type-inference, ambiguous

```
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}

data Foo = Foo {fld::Int}
data Bar = Bar {foo::Foo}
data Baz = Baz {fld::Int}

getFldFromFoo :: Foo -> Int
getFldFromFoo = fld -- ok

getFldFromBaz :: Baz -> Int
getFldFromBaz = fld -- ok

getFldFromBar :: Bar -> Int
getFldFromBar = fld . foo  -- error: Ambiguous occurrence ‘fld’
-- getFldFromBar = (fld :: Foo -> Int) . foo -- ok
```

Why is `fld` ambigous? `Foo -> Int` and `Baz -> Int` are different types.
I thought that **ghc** can inferred the argument of `fld` from the type of `foo`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disambiguate selector function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37395098/how-to-disambiguate-selector-function)

Comment: This is, IMO, the main limitation of the extension. I have no idea about why GHC can not be made to accept this.

Comment: I reopened the question. The duplicates ask _how to_ disambiguate if necessary, this one asks _why_ it's necessary to disambiguate in the first place. (If somebody answers that in the other questions, we can close again, but nobody has as yet.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout A fair point. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41008295/2751851) might be a better target.

Comment: @leftaroundabout the answer to the question addressed why by quoting the GHC user's guide: "However, we do not infer the type of the argument to determine the datatype, or have any way of deferring the choice to the constraint solver."

Comment: I agree that this is a limitation of `DuplicatedRecordFields`... nevertheless, you can easily solve without type anotation using `getFldFromBar = getFldFromFoo . foo`